# New SSO for Custom Tab in Microsoft Teams

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

We want to implement SSO for a Custom Tab in Microsoft Teams.

I have seen new possibilities shown in the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLjT1Hw5a1E&t=39s)
(The relevant part is at 24m29s). Is this available yet?

If so, is there any documentation on this?

Comment: This might help too? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-silent-aad

Comment: That documentation proposes ADAL. My question is if this is still the correct way to go about this given newer possibilities

Comment: Haven't tested it at all, but https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/blob/master/Teams/04%20Fundamentals%20of%20Microsoft%20Teams/Lab.md#exercise3 uses MSAL. Maybe it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Nsevens. But this also illustrates my issue; official documentation shows ADAL, there are multiple examples in MSAL (but also reports that it does not work), and on Build 2019 a new way of doing authentication was presented, but I cannot find any details about is. I'm looking for an insider who points us in the correct direction, so we do not have to redo everything once we are done.

Comment: @Nsevens we followed the instruction in the link you said. But we we are not gettig back a token from acquireTokenSilent and/or acquireTokenPopup. The callback from msal is not being received. My colleague asked about this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605184/not-able-to-use-identity-platform-within-iframe-ms-teams-custom-tab). Conclusion is that this is related to https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/222.

Comment: Just been testing the same thing, and indeed, the acquireTokenSilent seems to fail :( I've seen the issue pop up as well at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/899
They're targeting release for end of september. Let's hope it works fine by then...

Comment: @Nsevens "They're targeting release for end of september. Let's hope it works fine by then.." I could not find that information anywhere. Could you share where you have seen the release date for this particular feature?

Comment: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/504#issuecomment-521039037
maybe too optimistic to go by, but it's all I have ;)